Movie with 3 horror stories: statues awake, jelly-like alien/ghost kills people at a lake
I saw a movie 15 to 20 years ago that told three separate horror stories.
The movie (which starts animated) starts with a boy riding a bicycle throwing a magazine. In one story some statues come awake. In another story, some men and women went to a lake, and inside the lake there's a jelly-like alien or ghost (or something) that kills the men and women.
What is the name of the movie?

Any chance you remember what language it was in and/or what country it was from?

Well from your description it sounds like the classic CREEPSHOW PART 2, 1987. This movie starts with a lad being thrown a paper/magazine then goes into animation preceding the start of the horror anthology. One of the stories is a wooden statue coming alive and another one is a group of people who go to a lake and are killed by a lake blob. There is a third story revolving around an undead hitchhiker rounding out the story.



Heh. I was guessing it might be one of the Creepshow movies, but I have never seen them.

My fav is the one in the 1982 Creepshow where a hapless farmer turns into a plant.

The thing my childhood nightmares were born of. That damn blob shudder
